# How can I test Golang code that calls users.Lookup with a virtual file system like Afero's in-memory FS?

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing

I'm trying to write tests for this function in Go:

```
type LinuxBackend struct {
    fs afero.Fs
}


func (b *LinuxBackend) GetSSHUser(name string) users.SSHUser {
    // Get the user from the system
    usr, err := user.Lookup(name)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return users.SSHUser{ User: usr }
}
```

I'd like to have a fake `/etc/passwd` so that my tests can create the necessary users in that file instead of relying on the real system file.

For other parts of my code, I abstracted the underlying file system using [Afero](https://github.com/spf13/afero) to create an in-memory file system, creating the necessary files (including `/etc/passwd`) so the tests can run. That's what the `fs` field in `LinuxBackend` is for.

For example, here's another function from the same package:

```
func (b *LinuxBackend) GetMinMaxUid() (int, int) {
    content, err := afero.ReadFile(b.fs, LoginDefsPath)
    // more code here...
    return min, max
}
```

I can then test this without touching the real file system:

```
func createLoginDefs(afs afero.Fs) {
    afs.MkdirAll("/etc", os.FileMode(os.ModeDir))
    f, _ := afs.OpenFile(LoginDefsPath, os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0600)
    defer f.Close()
    f.WriteString("UID_MIN           " + strconv.Itoa(uidMin) + "\n")
    f.WriteString("UID_MAX           " + strconv.Itoa(uidMax) + "\n")
}

func TestLinuxBackend_GetMinMaxUid(t *testing.T) {
    afs := afero.NewMemMapFs() // <-- This is the trick.
    createLoginDefs(afs)

    backend := LinuxBackend{afs}

    min, max := backend.GetMinMaxUid()

    // rest of the test...
}
```

I can't do that for [`user.Lookup()`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/os/user/lookup.go#L32), though, which means it will try to fetch the non-existent test users from the real file system.

`user.Lookup` calls `user.lookupUser`, which has two concrete implementations, a [pure Go](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/os/user/lookup_unix.go#L181) one, and a [cgo one](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/os/user/cgo_lookup_unix.go#L52). The latter is completely impossible to coerce to use a virtual file system, I believe, since it uses libc's `pw*` utility functions to fetch users. The former starts by `Open`ing a file handle and then passes it to a `findUsername` function that takes an `io.Reader` as an argument, but this function is not exported from the module, so I can't use it directly to pass a Reader from the Afero file system to it.

Is there a way I can somehow make Go use the in-memory file system for `user.Lookup` and `user.lookupUser`, or write the code or test in some other way so that `user.Lookup` doesn't use the real file system?

I could always copy `user.lookupUser` but I'd rather avoid that.

Comment: If you have a virtual file system (especially `/etc/passwd`), then it should work just fine. The internals for `user.Lookup` uses `/etc/passwd`. https://golang.org/src/os/user/lookup_unix.go#L181

Comment: Well, Go's internals don't know about my virtual file system, so `os.Open()` will just try to access `/etc/passwd` on my machine instead of the one in the in-memory file system. Unless there's a way for me to tell Go's `os` package to use the virtual file system, I don't see how it will use it. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The easiest thing to do might be to abstract the type `LinuxBackend` more to take a parameter for some sort of path (maybe the root of everything? I'd have to know more about your project to say for sure) so that way you can make spin up a variable of type `LinuxBackend` in your tests that either points to a) the virtual file system (if its mounted somewhere) or b) a clone temporary directory that you clean up at the end of the tests. Check out `testing.M` and `TestMain` to make some of this process easier.

Comment: LinuxBackend is just a struct that contains an Afero file system (I just added it in the question). That way I can instantiate an in-memory file system for tests or a regular file system for the other code. So in other words, I believe I already have the abstraction you mention but I still don't see how I could make Go's code use it.